# firebase realtime database return success with no internet connection

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase realtime database for an online game, android Kotlin.
when changing anything on the database I need to make sure all devices are in sync.
I use the updateChildren method to update 2 different object as a transaction, it is need to be done together at once. that's runTransction() method won't do good here.
my problem is when one device use updateChildren method to change data without internet connection, I see the following behavior:

1. no callbacks for the request listeners (no success or fail), the request waiting and will be executed when device regain connection and then I'm getting success callback.
2. This is the main problem: ValueEventListener fire the change like it's done on the device that execute the request. It is happening while it's offline, before it gets to the server. Other participants won't be in sync with this device since it's disconnected.
   The expected behaviour I need is like runTransaction() with the parameter fireLocalEvents = false. This way ValueEventListener not fire any callback before transaction is actually happens on server side.

I tried to remove "disconnected capabilities" using `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(false)` but there was no change
I also reviewed https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-handling-transactions-offline but it is more about how to let the user not feel he's disconnected, while I need the exact opposite.

Comment: You should not see a success callback if the write is performed while offline.  The callback will only occur when the write successfully reaches the server.  In your app, other listeners at that location will trigger, but that's just observing the local data, not the remote data.  You cannot make the database writes fail while offline - the SDK will always try to make sure writes eventually succeed if the app comes back online.

Comment: @DougStevenson I edited the question, I hope it will be more clear now

Comment: It sounds like you understand the behavior of the system, and have a solution that works in #2.  What else are you looking for?

Comment: @DougStevenson #2 is the main problem. it is realtime game. user can make a move offline and move forward in the game while other players stay behind, since the server not updated with his move

Comment: Transactions don't work at all while offline.  If you use a transaction, you should be able to use its failure to recover the way you want.

Comment: @DougStevenson any way to get the same behavior with updateChildren? I'm using it on this case to update 2 objects  in different places together, something that transaction can't do

Comment: If that's your actual question, please edit the post to describe what you're hoping to accomplish, along with the constraints you're working with.  The question in the post needs to be clear in order to get an answer.

Comment: @DougStevenson I hope it's all clear this time